How to Access HTC Dataset for Transport Mode Detection?
I've seen several research papers using the HTC dataset for transport mode detection, but I can't find a way to access it. Does anyone know how to obtain this dataset or whom to contact for access?
Any help would be appreciated!

If the usual means (google searches, asking colleagues, asking advisors) do not work, then you can contact people that used the data set in their research. This is not really a question for this forum.
